# Changing language programmatically in AEM 6.2+

Tags: javascript, internationalization, adobe, aem

Currently, our site is using AEM's i18n granite library to access translations for all things text.  We have set up our site using the recommended site structure so that AEM is aware of the language based on /content/.

I know that in Javascript, you can use the method `Granite.I18n.setLocale('<locale>')` to manually change the locale for I18n, but can it be done so that you can set the language and have the page immediately render with the new language?

Answer (score 0):

That is not advisable because it means the page can't be cached in the dispatcher and the publisher would be hit basically on every request.

You should rely on standard functionalities like language copies (https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/language-copy-feature-video-use.html), because otherwise the system might become really slow or unresponsive.